# how to create GCE instance via api

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, google-compute-engine

---

**dependent variables are:**

**$randomString** which is random string

**$num_rows[0]** which is correct access_token after oAuth 2.0 process

---

**Requet :**

> $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plenary-ability-439/zones/us-central1-a/disks?sourceImage=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20140318&access_token=".$num_rows[0];

```
    $params = array(

                "kind" => "compute#disk",
                "zone" => "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plenary-ability-439/zones/us-central1-a",
                "name" => $randomString,
                "description" => "any description "
            );
```

> ```
>           $ch = curl_init();
>
>             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);           
>
>           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
>           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
>           $headers = array("Content-Type: application/json" ); 
>           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
>
>
>           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
>           $result = curl_exec($ch);
>           $res = json_decode($result, true);
> ```
>
> ***Respnse :***
>
> {
>
> "error": {
>
> "errors": [
>
> {
>
> ```
> "domain": "global",
>
> "reason": "parseError",
>
> "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."
> ```
>
> }
>
> ],
>
> "code": 400,
>
> "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."
>
> }
>
> }

**$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json" );**  is onething i come know so far and i have set this correctly

**second things is : i also tried this but i got same response **

```
     $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer $num_rows[0]", 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing http GET request to the google. So use this one:

```
$sourceImage = urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20140318');
$access_token = urlencode($num_rows[0]);
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plenary-ability-439/zones/us-central1-a/disks?sourceImage=$sourceImage&access_token=$access_token";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$res = json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: Hanssan : it is not working in any case i have tried with Google client lib in python

Answer (score 0):

The access_token should not be part of the URL

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plenary-ability-439/zones/us-central1-a/disks?sourceImage=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20140318

Access token becomes part of the header

```
{'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + access_token, 
'x-goog-api-version': version,
'x-goog-project-id': project_id,
'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

Also how are you getting the access_token, I am guessing you are using metadata server to get it.

Refer https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#applications